# Java Web Start Questions

Tags: java, javafx, jnlp, java-web-start

My company has been developing a desktop application for a long time and have been installing it with Installshield on Windows machines.

But because we are going to add JavaFX to the application we cannot deploy it the way we used to so I am looking into Java Web Start as a way to move forward.  But I am totally lost on it and want to ask some questions.

1) There does not seem to be any recent document discussing it, all the docs on the Oracle site seem to be older then 2005 some as old as 2001.  Is Java Web Start still viable?

2) My application needs access to the file system, dll's and what not.  It discusses needing to sign my code, but I see no real documents on how to do this and even then how do I do this for the specific need of Java Web Start so that I immediately have access to the file system.

3) I need to put on the file system files other then my jar file, such as image files and other jar and dll files.  Can I do that in Java Web Start?

4) Can our application have more then one entry point?  Basically we offer a suite of applications that each have menu entries from the start menu (all the entry points are in the main jar file).  Can this be done?

5) Can my application be available to all users of the computer using a shared set of config files?

6) On Windows I HAVE no choice but to use ONLY 32 bit Java and JavaFX because of the DLL's we package with the system so even on 64 bit machines I need to have 32 bit Java loaded and  make sure only the 32 bit Java launches my program.  Can this be done with Java Web Start?

Sorry for my ignorance.

Bodger

Comment: 1) I would not worry about old docs. It's not such a big topic and is not updated much anymore. 2) look up how to sign applets, should be the same

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes, definitely still available.  I use it nearly every day on our apps!

2) Yes, code needs to be signed.  Can't tell you how to do it off-hand though, I use Netbeans and it's got a simple "push this button and all the signing magic happens automatically" setup.

3-4)  Good questions. I *think* so, but am not sure.  I've only had to manually tweak a couple of Java Web Start files on very rare occasions.  Can't remember what can be done and what can't.

5) Not sure exactly what you mean by that.  Shared config files on Windows ends up going down this ugly road of dealing with UAC (some other platforms have similar permissions issues as well).

6) I can't think of a way to explicitly enforce 32-bit launches, but 32-bit is the standard, you have to go out of your way to use 64-bit Java...  I suppose you could have a user that does go through all the contortions of launching it in 64-bit, but that seems like one of those outliers that you might be able to just say "well, don't fiddle with that stuff".  :-)

Comment: I need to solve the 32 bit problem because of the DLL's we issue with our Windows deployment only work with jni on 32 bit Java.

Comment: I get the reason for the concern, but it may be misplaced.  Is it realistic that any of your customers would either a) Have the 64-bit JRE installed, but NOT the 32-bit one or b) try to force your app to launch 64-bit when they have both JREs (32-bit is the default)?

Comment: The default version of the JRE that is downloaded and installed on Windows 64 bit machines is the 64 bit version of Java and it is causing me all sorts of pain and agony.

Comment: Interesting, I've never seen that behaviour.  Other than developers that specifically download the 64-bit version, I only see the 32-bit version on machines in the wild.  Seems like you could throw an error in your app and point people at the right version though, if you can't do it in JNLP itself.

Answer (score 2):

1). Cant say, i have stopped developing WebStart for Clients several years ago.

2&3). Yes you use the security setting in your config/start (jnlp) file.

```
<security>
    <all-permissions/>
<security>
```

For the security you need the users permission which requires the application (basically all jars) to be signed.

4). Yes. Webstart can create links on the users desktop that use a specific jnlp file. This file includes the entry point.

```
<application-desc main-class="us.fl.k12....letters.clients.Main"/>
```

5). Since you can copy your config files to a folder shared by all users i would say yes.

Also AFAIK all resources need to be bundled inside jars.

Edit: Very useful http://lopica.sourceforge.net/faq.html

Edit2: 2). You can self sign your jars if you are using the app in house. There is no need for a fancy certificate. See http://wiki.plexinfo.net/index.php?title=How_to_sign_JAR_files for an easy way to create your own certificate.